# How to setup phpmyadmin and SQL for messaging via REST-api?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my database I have a table called "Chat". Here i intend to store every message that has been sent between users in my application. First i have to store them in a list (by just simply doing a `SELECT * FROM ColumnText WHERE OneID = '$OneID'` and gather all the ID's from other users i have had messages with) but i now struggle to finish the last part which is to see the messages between these two users once i click on a row.

My plan is to gather the info with a call that would look something like this:

```
http://myURL.com/Chat.php?UserOneID=1548&UserTwoID=1724
```

Where one user has ID `1548` and another `1724`.

The first issue I am seeing is that who will I know which one sent the message. What i then did and that could potentially work is to do something like this instead:

Rename the ID's to something more clear like this first `SenderID` and `RecieverID` instead where the data could look something like this:

`SenderID = 1548` `RecieverID = 1724`

and

`SenderID = 1724` `RecieverID = 1548`

I wrote code for it that looks like this where i use a `UNION` to try to gather the data for the two ID's together, not just one ID where the call would look something like this:

```
http://myURL.com/Chat.php?SenderID=1548&RecieverID=1724
http://myURL.com/Chat.php?RecieverID=1548&SenderID=1724


<?php

class ConnectionInfo 
{   
public $conn; 
public function GetConnection() {
  $this->conn = mysqli_connect("serv", "user","pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));

 }
}

$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
echo 'No Connection';
}

else
{
    $SenderID = $_GET['SenderID'];
    $RecieverID = $_GET['RecieverID'];

    $query = "(SELECT * FROM ColumnText WHERE SenderID = '$SenderID') UNION (SELECT * FROM ColumnText WHERE RecieverID = '$RecieverID')";

    $stmt = mysqli_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

    if (!$stmt)
    {
        echo 'Query failed';
    }

    else
    {
        $contacts = array(); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) 
        {

        $contact = array("Messages" => $row['Messages']);

        array_push($contacts, $contact);         
        }
        echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

}

?>
```

The problem with this is that "UNION" does not seem to do the trick. I only seem to get all the data from the `SenderID` row even though the RecieverID is not matching with the one i send to the script.

Is my current approach the correct way and if so, how would i need to adjust my phpscript in order for this to work?

Comment: Would love to get feedback from the person who downvoted in order to adjust and edit the post accordingly.

Comment: I think you want to join the data...

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_join.asp ?

Comment: no sql join... `SELECT *
  FROM chat c1
  JOIN chat c2
    ON c1.senderId = c2.receiverId
 WHERE c1.sender_id = '$SenderID'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don‘t you just use an `OR`? So the results have the correct receiver and the correct sender? And you got all messages from X to Y and all messages from Y to X

Your query line would look like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ColumnText WHERE (SenderID = '$SenderID' AND RecieverID = '$RecieverID') OR (SenderID = '$RecieverID' AND RecieverID = '$SenderID')“;
```

Furthermore i strongly recommend you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I did that before. The problem with this is that "SenderID" and "RecieverID" keeps switching around depending on who wrote. So if i do `SenderID=17&RecieverID=18` then I only get the "Sender" ones if i then switch it up `RecieverID=17&SenderID=18` then i get the "Sender" ones from the other user. I want them all at once with one URL call.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Now that's a accurate description. @CarlosRodrigez Check out my answer again, i updated it!

Comment: Perfect, that was it :) Do u think this is a good way to create a messagingsystem?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Well, it's up to your definition of "good". There is no right or wrong. As one of your first approaches with PHP and Chatsystems it's quite fine yeah. If you go for huge businesses or pretty huge chat system you should rather use Erlang or node or sth similar to build a chat system since PHP is not suited that good for real time messaging. But for learning or medium usage your approch is totally fine!