# How to only push out JSON for a unique row in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table is setup like this "SenderID", "RecieverID" and "Message".
In other words there is a lot of messages in there but i've setup my code to only get the ID's that is connected to the ID i am sending in. I do this with a rest-api call looking like this:

```
http://myurl.com/Chat.php?UserID=18
```

Where the code then push out every opposite ID of the person the user have been messaging with. The problem that i am having though is that I only want to gather the opposite ID once, so if multiple messages have been made between user ID 18 and for instance 17, then the JSON pushes it out multiple times instead of just 1.

This is what it looks like now:

```
{ "results": 
  [ 
    { "SenderID": "17", "RecieverID": "18" }, 
    { "SenderID": "18", "RecieverID": "17" },
    { "SenderID": "17", "RecieverID": "18" }, 
    { "SenderID": "17", "RecieverID": "18" }
  ] 
}
```

When in reality i want it to only push that out once to see if they have ever messaged eachother. Like this:

```
{ "results": 
  [ 
    { "SenderID": "17", "RecieverID": "18" }, //push it out once
    { "SenderID": "18", "RecieverID": "34" } //then it will carry on to push out other matched id's
  ] 
}
```

Whether the ID sent in was a "SenderID" (sent message) or "RecieverID" (recieved message) is not something that is important. I just need to see if they have ever messaged by comparing both ID's.

This is my code:

```
<?php

class ConnectionInfo 
{   
    public $conn; 
    public function GetConnection() {

    $this->conn = mysqli_connect("serv", "user","pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));

    }

}

$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
     echo 'No Connection';
}

else
{
    $UserID = $_GET['UserID'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (SenderID = '$UserID') OR (RecieverID = '$UserID')";


    $stmt = mysqli_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

    if (!$stmt)
    {
        echo 'Query failed';
    }

    else
    {
        $contacts = array(); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) 
        {
            $contact = array("SenderID" => $row['SenderID'],"RecieverID" => $row['RecieverID']);
            array_push($contacts, $contact); 
        }

        echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
?>
```

[image]
With the matched ID's i then load a conversation that i alrdy solved with another thread i made: [How to setup phpmyadmin and SQL for messaging via REST-api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190247/how-to-setup-phpmyadmin-and-sql-for-messaging-via-rest-api/50190392#50190392)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR`s in `WHERE` clauses can sometimes generate duplicates, and your table can possibly contain duplicates. Your query should remove them.  Try this

```
     SELECT DISTINCT SenderID, RecieverID
      FROM MyTable
     WHERE SenderID = '$UserID' OR RecieverID = '$UserID'
```

If, given a UserID, you want a list of every other user that has sent a message to and/or received a message from that user, do this

```
    SELECT SenderId FROM MyTable WHERE RecieverID = '$UserID'
    UNION
    SELECT RecieverID FROM MyTable WHERE SenderId = '$UserID'
```

`UNION`, a set operation, removes the duplicates.

Comment: Ok this is some improvements, now i only get 2 rows. The reason i get two now is because with this user that has an id of 17, i have both sent a message but also recieved a message, which means that the senderid is once 17 and another time 18. Anyway this could also be improven?

Comment: It's hard to give more advice unless we see a sample of the contents of your table. You could edit your question.

Comment: Maybe its easier to just create a new table and store only the ID's there once a conversation has been started. Not use the actual messagetable.

Comment: Works very well now! THanks a ton

Comment: One quick question @O. Jones. What if we want to use the ObjectID in the table as well? Lets say that the discussion between user 17 and user 18 once contains objectid 15 and then another time it contains 19. Is it possible to push it these two then?

Comment: Oh i solved that myself i just added "ObjectID" after "SenderID, __"